# Limitations of programmatically phone call on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Are there limits imposed by Apple for the programmatically phone calls on iPhone?
I don't know which document i've to read.

Comment: What kind of functionality are you trying to do here? The only thing your user should be able to do from your app is originate a call. Most other things would have privacy concerns from Apple and therefore not be likely to be acceptable into the app store.

Comment: i want to start a call fired by a NSTimer after a certain delay

Comment: Nothing to prevent you, technically, from doing that. But why would you? To trigger call that is not immediately in response to user interaction seems like questionable design. But maybe I'm not understanding why you'd got through the trouble of setting up the NSTimer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger a call directly but you can use a URL Scheme to prompt the user to start a call. 
You can do that using the openURL method of AppDelegate. 
Here's a list of all the kind of things you can do like this ( including the call ). It should be easy enough to make NSTimer trigger this.

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone

Comment: yep, i know. My problem was more on "if i can do" rather then "how i can do" :)